# Best Relationship to choose in the scenario

Tags: custom-object, lookup, relationships, master-detail

I got a below query, which have single answer. And I was able to filter down 2 answers for it.

A company has a custom object named Warehouse. Each Warehouse record has a **distinct record owner**, and is related to parent Account in Salesforce.
Which kind of relationship would the developer use to relate the Account to the warehouse?

A. One-to-Many

B. Lookup

C. Master-Detail

D. Parent-Child

I got answer as B or C. Can you help me to identify correct one from these 2 choices and understand the reason as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Lookup relationship since it's mentioned clearly as distinct record owner. In master detail, master objects only have owner.

So Answer is B.